# Javascript toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript

Hi the problem is following:

I define:

```
var total = 0;

function add(a){
  total+=a;
  var float_num = total.toFixed(2);
  return float_num;
}
```

The JS give me an error said Uncaught TypeError total.toFixed is not a function

**I don't get it. the total I declare is not a number type?**

Comment: Make sure total is a number.

Comment: I just run your code in chrome console, and every thing seems fine. where did you testes your code?

Comment: @khanmizan: Try `add("1")`. It would give the error. Which is what I assume is happening and is an easy mistake to make if you take input from a web page.

Comment: oh right you are. in that I think you have to use `parseFloat(a)`

Comment: I found the problem. My some other function has a code that xxx.text(total). It actually convert total back to string. That cause the problem.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 20):

I think the easiest way to prevent the error from happening is to always parse the parameter as number:

```
var total = 0;
function add(a){
  total+=a;
  var float_num = Number(total).toFixed(2);
  return float_num;
}
```

Comment: Can we get this as the Accepted answer, someone who has permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of the code above has redefined the toFixed on the Number prototype, For instance

```
Number.prototype.toFixed = {};

var total = 0;

function add(a) {
    total += a;
    var float_num = total.toFixed(2);
    return float_num;
}

add(2)
```

is one way to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the value of `a`. If `a` happens to be a `"string"` then you're trying to do:

```
"0string".toFixed(2)
```

which should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var total = 1.0;

function add(a) {
    total += a;
    var float_num = total.toFixed(2);
    return float_num;
}

console.log(add(4.89));
```

This code is a bit unsafe since you assume that a is a float and not a string.

https://jsfiddle.net/6to7kbbm/

This will throw the exception:

```
var total = 1.0;

function add(a) {
    total += a;
    var float_num = total.toFixed(2);
    return float_num;
}

console.log(add("4.89"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've just run your code a few times, and I can confirm that your `.toFixed()` line is working just fine.

However, it only works if you pass a numeric value into the function. If the `a` parameter is not numeric, then `toFixed()` will fail as described.

So **the problem isn't with the function, but how you're calling it.** In your question, you're not showing how you're calling the function, so I can't give you any direct guidance on that, other than to make sure that you're giving it a numeric every time.

Maybe you're passing in a string? That would break things (even if the string does contain a numeric value).

Or maybe it's a `null` or `undefined` or `NaN` due to an error or oversight elsewhere in your system? I can't tell, but in those cases you probably don't want to be calling the `add()` function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My some other function has a code that xxx.text(total). It actually convert total back to string. That cause the problem.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have any declared function with the same name as the variable you are using. To prevent this you may declare global variables like:

```
var global_variable = 0;
function myfunction()
{
    var variable = 0; 
    global_variable = variable + 1;
}
```